# SQL syntax multiple joins?

Tags: sql

I have a two tables,Transaction and Master.  The transaction table shows a from and to activity id.  The master shows the activity id and a name.  The from and to id use the same master table to associate the activity id and name.  What I would like to do is take the distinct from and to values and display them with the associated name.

The original query was

```
select distinct a.from, a.to from Transaction a
```

What I need is something where a.from is followed by b.name and a.to is followed by b.name

I know that I have to have a join but I need the join to apply to each of the distinct a.values.

In concept I would like to do 2 joins with one on each of the a.values but I am not sure how to delineate the from and to values.

Comment: Join the Master table twice.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4267979/12601

Comment: Can you add a simple example with, say, 3 columns from each table and an example of the output you want from the query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select distinct a.from, f.name as FromName, a.to, t.name as ToName 
from Transaction a
join Master F on a.from = f.id
join Master T on a.to = f.id
```

Comment: This is what Greg suggested also.  By giving the same table two aliases I am able to join the two fields independently of each other.  Thanks to everyone who helped.