# After I Join with same table twice then how to call value with same column name in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll start with an example:

```
*Table1*
ID
PhoneNumber1
PhoneNumber2

*Table2*
PhoneNumber
SomeOtherField

SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
   ON t2.PhoneNumber = t1.PhoneNumber1
INNER JOIN Table2 t3
   ON t3.PhoneNumber = t1.PhoneNumber2
-- here is the question how do I call same column which have same name?
-- I want to do a where clause like below:
WHERE SomeOtherField(from first Table2) = SomeOtherField(from second Table2)
```

The example is from below question, but we are asking different things:
[What's the best way to join on the same table twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267929/whats-the-best-way-to-join-on-the-same-table-twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE t2.SomeOtherField = t1.SomeOtherField
```