# SQL- link two columns from one table to single column from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that holds **Tasks details** and a table that holds **users details.**
Each Task has two relations with the users table as following:

**Tasks table** : TaskID, Name, Description, TaskCreatorId, TaskPICId 
**Users table** : UserId, Name, E-mail
Where TaskCreatorId is linked to UserId, and TaskPICId is also Linked to UserId.
Now how i make a query to list all tasks with Taskcreator name and TaskPIC name 
[Tasks table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUQif.png)

[Users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIL6P.png)

Comment: hi please share sample data and expected result

Comment: try my answer if any issues please let me know

Comment: Hi @Emad Ali, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please do not take this personally, but you really should try and put a little more effort into searching the existing questions/answers before rephrasing an all too familiar problem again. Your problem was already discussed and solved more than 6 years ago, as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267929/whats-the-best-way-to-join-on-the-same-table-twice

Comment: @cars10 Thank u. Sorry I'm still new here and maybe i have used the wrong keyword for search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the user information to the task information at two different points.

```
SELECT 
    t.TaskID, 
    t.Name, 
    t.Description, 
    t.TaskCreatorId,  
    u1.Name as TaskCreatorName, 
    u1.[E-mail] as TaskCreatorEMail,
    t.TaskPICId,
    u2.Name as TaskPICName,
    u2.[E-mail] as TaskPICEMail
FROM 
    Tasks t 
    LEFT JOIN Users u1 ON u1.userId = t.TaskCreatorId
    LEFT JOIN Users u2 ON u2.userId = t.TaskPICId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to tun this:

```
                        declare @tuser as table (id int , name varchar(10))
            declare @ttask as table (tid int , cid int )

            insert into @tuser(id,name) values(1,'a')
            insert into @tuser (id,name)values(2,'b')
            insert into @ttask  values(1,2)


            select u.name as nm1  , u1.name as cname, t.* from @ttask  t left join @tuser u on u.id = t.tid 
            left join @tuser u1 on   u1.id= t.cid
```

Comment: Your query will return only records where TaskCreatorId and TaskPICId are the same. I need two differt columns one for creator name and one for PIC name

Comment: ok can you please share sample data please to answer it corrrectly

Comment: I upload 2 pic for the tables.

Comment: I didn't try it because I'm still new to SQL and i can't understand your query very well so for now i will take Fritz answer .Thanks for your help :)