# SQL join multiple tables with one column becoming two

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables that I want to join. One table has fields that need to be broken out of one column to become two columns.
Here are sample tables.

**Doors**

| DoorID | DoorType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | B |
| 5 | A |
| 6 | A |
| 7 | A |

**Parts**

| PartID | DoorID | Description | MaterialID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Hinge | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Hinge | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | Hinge | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | Hinge | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | Hinge | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | Hinge | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | Plate | 3 |
| 8 | 1 | Plate | 3 |
| 9 | 2 | Plate | 3 |
| 10 | 2 | Plate | 3 |
| 11 | 3 | Plate | 3 |
| 12 | 3 | Plate | 3 |
| 13 | 4 | Plate | 3 |
| 14 | 4 | Plate | 3 |
| 15 | 5 | Hinge | 2 |
| 16 | 5 | Hinge | 2 |
| 17 |  | Deck | 33 |
| 18 |  | Unfinished Left End | 33 |
| 19 |  | Partition | 38 |
| 20 | 5 | Plate | 4 |
| 21 | 5 | Plate | 4 |

**Materials**

| MaterialID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/8 Hinge |
| 2 | 5/8 Hinge |
| 3 | 3/8 Plate |
| 4 | 5/8 Plate |
| 33 | 1/2 Birch Ply |
| 38 | 3/4 Birch Ply |

What I'd like to end up with is a count of each door type and what hinge and hinge plate is on each door type like the following. All of the A doors are counted together except the one that has no hinges. All of the B doors are counted together. Any part that's not a hinge or plate is ignored. Any material that's not a hinge or plate is ignored. Any door type that has no hinge or
plate leaves those fields blank.

Door Count with Hinge Data:

| Qty | Hinge | Plate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3/8 Hinge | 3/8 Plate |
| 2 | 5/8 Hinge | 5/8 Plate |
| 1 |  |  |

I've been beating my head against a wall on this for hours and am not getting anywhere. I'm very new to SQL as well. I have discovered that the application I'm using doesn't support CASE statements at all, but it can use IIF functions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess you are using DB which is  MYSQL and not SQL , looking at your restrictions with CASE,  in MYSQL, CASE statement is allowed only in stored procedures. I will try and come up with an answer to your problem soon, meanwhile please verify your DB and update the tag accordingly because specific tags attract appropriate audience.

Comment: @GSM: SQL is quite separate from (MS) SQL Server.  I agree the question should be tagged with the DBMS in use.  However, the SQL tag is generic for any DBMS which uses SQL as the query language; there are specific tags for SQL Server (quite a lot of them, many corresponding to release versions).

Comment: now my answer works; careful that door 4 has no hinge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT 
    count(DoorID) as Qty, Hinge, Plate 
FROM 
    ( SELECT D.DoorID as DoorID,
        group_concat(distinct IF(PH.Description = 'Hinge', MH.Name, NULL)) as Hinge, 
        group_concat(distinct IF(PP.Description = 'Plate', MP.Name, NULL)) as Plate
        FROM Doors as D
        LEFT JOIN Parts as PH
            ON D.DoorID = PH.DoorID
        LEFT JOIN Materials as MH
            ON PH.MaterialID = MH.MaterialID
        LEFT JOIN Parts as PP
            ON D.DoorID = PP.DoorID
        LEFT JOIN Materials as MP
            ON PP.MaterialID = MP.MaterialID
    GROUP BY D.DoorID ) as subquery
GROUP BY Hinge, Plate
```

like how is done in those [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267929/whats-the-best-way-to-join-on-the-same-table-twice).

Comment: Thanks. This was the biggest help in figuring out how to get what I wanted, though I had to do it a little different. The main thing I was missing was the ability to use two different aliases for the same table. My solution was to create a table joining Parts and Materials in a different query, then aliasing that table twice to pull the hinge name and plate name out into different columns. This avoided the need for any CASE or IIF since I could just use WHILE to filter the first query and a second ON condition to separate the hinge names and plate names during the join in the second query.

Answer (score -1):

Since you discovered your application has problem with CASE, will try and device a query with alternative IIF statement

```
SELECT SUM(D.DoorType) AS Qty,     
    IIF( P.Description = 'Hinge', M.Name , '') AS Hinge,       
    IIF( P.Description = 'Plate', M.Name , '') AS Plate       
FROM Doors D , Materials M , Parts P     
WHERE D.DoorID = P.DoorID     
    AND P.MaterialID = M.MaterialID     
    AND P.Description IN('Hinge' , 'Plate')    
GROUP BY D.DoorType
ORDER BY D.DoorType
```